# How to get the sibling of an xml node

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file as below

```
<Games>
   <Game>
      <name>Tzoker</name>
      <file>tzoker1</file>
   </Game>
   <Game>
      <file>lotto770</file>
   </Game>
   <Game>
      <name>Proto</name>
      <file>proto220</file>
   </Game>
</Games>
```

I want to get the values of name and file items for every Game node.
It is easy by using this query.

```
string query = String.Format("//Games/Game");
 XmlNodeList elements1 = xml.SelectNodes(query);
 foreach (XmlNode xn in elements1)
 {
   s1 = xn["name"].InnerText;
   s2 = xn["file"].InnerText;
 }
```

The problem is that there are some nodes that they don't have the name item. So the code above doesn't work.
I have solved the problem by using the following code

```
string query = String.Format("//Games/Game/name");
XmlNodeList elements1 = xml.SelectNodes(query);
foreach (XmlNode xn in elements1)
{
  s1 = xn.InnerText;
  string query1 = String.Format("//Games/Game[name='{0}']/file", s1);
  XmlNodeList elements2 = xml.SelectNodes(query1);
  foreach (XmlNode xn2 in elements2)
  {
    s2 = xn2.InnerText;
  }
}
```

The problem is that there is a case that two or more nodes have the same name value. So, the s2 variable will get the file value of the last node that the loop finds. So, I would like to find a way to get the sibling file value of the current name item. How could I do it? I try do move to the parent node of the current node and then to move to the file item but without success by using the following code.

```
string query = String.Format("//Games/Game/name");
XmlNodeList elements1 = xml.SelectNodes(query);
foreach (XmlNode xn in elements1)
{
   s1 = xn.InnerText;
   string query1 = String.Format("../file");
   XmlNodeList elements2 = xml.SelectNodes(query1);
   foreach (XmlNode xn2 in elements2)
   {
     s2 = xn2.InnerText;
   }
}
```

I hope there is a solution.

Comment: Research effort to address the actual problem, plus minimal and *almost* complete sample codes that demonstrate the problem. Excellent first question, I would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Game[name]` to filter `Game` elements to those with child element `name`. This is possible because `child::` is the default axes which will be implied when no explicit axes mentioned. Extending this further to check for child element `file` as well, would be as simple as `Game[name and file]` :

```
string query = String.Format("//Games/Game[name]");
XmlNodeList elements1 = xml.SelectNodes(query);
foreach (XmlNode xn in elements1)
{
   s1 = xn["name"].InnerText;
   s2 = xn["file"].InnerText;
}
```

---

Now to answer your question literally, you can use `following-sibling::` axes to get sibling element that follows current context element. So, given the context element is `name`, you can do `following-sibling::file` to return the sibling `file` element.

---

Your attempt which uses `../file` should also work. The only problem was, that your code executes that XPath on `xml`, the `XmlDocument`, instead of executing it on current `name` element :

```
XmlNodeList elements2 = xn.SelectNodes("../file");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to find all games that have a name. You can do that using XPath. Here is a solution that uses LINQ to XML. I find that easier to work with than `XmlDocument`:

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var games = xDocument
  .Root
  .XPathSelectElements("Game[child::name]")
  .Select(
    gameElement => new {
      Name = gameElement.Element("name").Value,
      File = gameElement.Element("file").Value
    }
  );
```

The XPath to select all `<Game>` elements that have a `<name>` child element is `Game[child::name]`.